# What is the syntax for a cron job that runs 15 and 45 minutes after the hour?

Tags: cron

What is the syntax for a cron job that runs 15 and 45 minutes after the hour? (So every 30 minutes.)

Would the syntax be something like:

```
15,45,30   *       *       *       *       wget -O /dev/null http://somesite.com/4_leads.php
```

So for example it would run at

```
2:15
2:45
3:15
3:45
4:15
4:45
```

and so on

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From [`man 5 crontab`](http://crontab.org/)

```
field          allowed values
-----          --------------
minute         0-59
hour           0-23
day of month   1-31
month          1-12 (or names, see below)
day of week    0-7 (0 or 7 is Sun, or use names)
```

Or, in other words

```
# m   h   dom mon dow   user          command
15,45 *    *   *   *    yourusername  wget -O /dev/null http://somesite.com/4_leads.php
```

Skip the username field if you place the entry in a user specific crontab, via `crontab -e`, `crontab -e -u yourusername`, or similar.

This question may be better suited to [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cron).